# Can't get image to fit background of body element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently sitting here trying to write a decent looking login page for my xfce setup.

I'm wanting the profile picture and background image to change when someone inputs the wrong password. I currently got it working to the point where it changes the background but it doesn't stretch it to fit my screen as I need the javascript to run `background-size: cover;`.

My current javascript line is currently `document.body.style.background = " #000000 url('images/bg.gif') no-repeat center fixed";` JQuery is not an option, don't ask why. It just isn't.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Give a way to re-create it, a jsfiddle or a codepen or something would be appreciated. If you have your css right, then changing the background image wouldn't matter.

Comment: Why not show us more of your code (eg. on JSFiddle)?

Comment: I'd love to, if I could actually get the jsfiddle to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover"` to force the background to "fill the screen", as you say.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Is it possible to also change the avatar? It's just a normal <img> tag.

Comment: @war10ck thanks for wrapping code in back ticks.    @realsub, yes you would access the `src` attribute in much the same way, something like `imgObject.setAttribute('src', 'path/to/new/avatar.jpg')` or `imgObject.src = "path/to/new/avatar.jpg'`

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm gonna try to get lightdm to listen to the avatar location defined in the html & js documents.
It's currently listening to a config file in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/` using the following path: `Icon=/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/illidan` 
Haven't figured out how to make it not listen to the config and use the html instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended (much easier and maintainable) to use CSS classes to style your page and to use JS to switch classes.

So, in your case, JavaScript can be something like:

```
document.body.className = 'wrong-password';
```

and CSS would be:

```
<style>
   .wrong-password {
      background: #000000 url('images/bg.gif') no-repeat center fixed;
      background-size: cover;
   }
</style>
```

And you can easily add more styles, or even change children's style (e.g. avatar) easily, like so:

```
<style>
   .wrong-password .avatar {
      display: none;
   }

   .wrong-password .some-placeholder {
      display: block;
   }
</style>
```